# Sign in with Apple in .Net MAUI

Tags: c#, android, ios, .net, maui

I am currently working on an dotnet maui app and I need to integrate Sign in With Apple. But when I click the sign in button, It shows "invalid_request invalid web redirect url"

**Tried solutions**

I tried the solutions available [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/122536), but it is not working.

Other than that I have also read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/configuring_your_environment_for_sign_in_with_apple), also got help from tutorials such as [this](https://clerk.dev/docs/authentication/social-login-with-apple),  [this](https://auth0.com/blog/what-is-sign-in-with-apple-a-new-identity-provider) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BxNpGkMyGes)

**Code**

Initializing request:

```
//Initiating apple sign in request
WebAuthenticatorResult result = null;

            if (scheme.Equals(Constants.apple, StringComparison.Ordinal)
                && DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.iOS
                && DeviceInfo.Version.Major >= 13)
            {
                // Make sure to enable Apple Sign In in both the
                // entitlements and the provisioning profile.
                var options = new AppleSignInAuthenticator.Options
                {
                    IncludeEmailScope = true,
                    IncludeFullNameScope = true,
                };
                result = await AppleSignInAuthenticator.AuthenticateAsync(options);
            }
            else
            {
                var authUrl = new Uri(Constants.authenticationUrl + scheme);
                var callbackUrl = new Uri(Constants.callbackUrl);

                result = await WebAuthenticator.AuthenticateAsync(authUrl, callbackUrl);
            }

            AuthToken = string.Empty;

            // Get Name and Email from callback url
            //if (result.Properties.TryGetValue("name", out var name) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
            //    AuthToken += $"Name: {name}{Environment.NewLine}";
            //if (result.Properties.TryGetValue("email", out var email) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
            //    AuthToken += $"Email: {email}{Environment.NewLine}";

            AuthToken += result?.AccessToken ?? result?.IdToken;


            AuthCredential credential = null;
```

**Handling results:**

```
// WebAuthenticator Endpoint - use for social login e.g. Google, Facebook, Apple etc.

    const string callbackScheme = "socialloginauthenticator";

    [HttpGet("{scheme}")]
    public async Task Get([FromRoute] string scheme)
    {
        var auth = await Request.HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(scheme);

        if (!auth.Succeeded
            || auth?.Principal == null
            || !auth.Principal.Identities.Any(id => id.IsAuthenticated)
            || string.IsNullOrEmpty(auth.Properties.GetTokenValue("access_token")))
        {
            // Not authenticated, challenge
            await Request.HttpContext.ChallengeAsync(scheme);
        }
        else
        {
            var claims = auth.Principal.Identities.FirstOrDefault()?.Claims;
            var email = string.Empty;
            email = claims?.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Email)?.Value;

            // Get parameters to send back to the callback
            var qs = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "access_token", auth.Properties.GetTokenValue("access_token") },
                { "refresh_token", auth.Properties.GetTokenValue("refresh_token") ?? string.Empty },
                { "expires_in", (auth.Properties.ExpiresUtc?.ToUnixTimeSeconds() ?? -1).ToString() },
                { "email", email }
            };

            // Build the result url
            var url = callbackScheme + "://#" + string.Join(
                "&",
                qs.Where(kvp => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(kvp.Value) && kvp.Value != "-1")
                .Select(kvp => $"{WebUtility.UrlEncode(kvp.Key)}={WebUtility.UrlEncode(kvp.Value)}"));

            // Redirect to final url
            Request.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(url);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue. The issue was with redirect uri in apple service I made.

The required uri was of format "www.example.com/signin-apple" while I was following "www.example.com/path/to/endpoints"

Comment: Hi Ahmad, can you show more of the service, where are you setting this uri?

Comment: @jimmy I am sorry but I don't have access to that code anymore.